# Nomencl Reference Section Number

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, nomenclature

I'm writing a PhD thesis that includes many similar symbols.  Therefore, I'd like to list in the nomenclature the section number at which each symbol is initially using (and therefore defined in the text).  I'm aware you can list the page number, but I'd prefer the section number.  Is there a way to do this?

Here's a minimal example what I have at the moment to define the section number, although this requires me to manually check each reference is correct:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
    \printnomenclature

    \chapter{Structural Analysis} \label{sec:Structural Analysis}
    \section{Sectional Properties} \label{sec:Sectional Properties}
    The cross-sectional area is defined as
    \begin{equation} \label{eqn:Cross-sectional area}
        A = \int_{S} \: dS
    \end{equation}
    \nomenclature{$A$}{cross-sectional area, m$^{2}$ (\ref{sec:Sectional Properties})}
    \nomenclature{$S$}{arbitrary surface (\ref{sec:Sectional Properties})}

\end{document}
```

I tried using `\thesection` as the reference but as expected this value was calculated during when creating the nomenclature, not at the position of `\nomenclature`.

I imagine there should be a way to do this through programming but haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) No need to add thanks and signature. Your user badge is automatically added to the post and you can show your gratitude by upvoting any good answers you may receive. We select to dothings this way to make posts more concise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that the section number is known at the moment you issue the `\nomenclature` command.

Here's a way to do it with a new command:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\newcommand{\mynomencl}[3][section]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
  \unexpanded{\nomenclature{#2}}%
    {\unexpanded{#3} (\csname the#1\endcsname)}}\x}

\begin{document}
\printnomenclature

\chapter{Structural Analysis} \label{sec:Structural Analysis}
\section{Sectional Properties} \label{sec:Sectional Properties}

The cross-sectional area is defined as
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:Cross-sectional area}
  A = \int_{S} \, dS
\end{equation}
\mynomencl{$A$}{cross-sectional area, m$^{2}$}
\mynomencl{$S$}{arbitrary surface}

\chapter{Structural Analysis} \label{sec:Structural Analysis2}
\section{Sectional Properties} \label{sec:Sectional Properties2}
The cross-sectional area is defined as
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:Cross-sectional area2}
  A = \int_{S} \, dS
\end{equation}
\mynomencl[chapter]{$A2$}{cross-sectional area, m$^{2}$}
\mynomencl{$S2$}{arbitrary surface}

\end{document}
```

The `\mynomencl` command has an optional argument for specifying the sectional units the entry should refer to (default `section`).

How does it work? The command `\mynomencl` stores in `\x` the `\nomenclature{...}{... (<number>)}` command, without expanding anything except for the last part (the number). Then it *executes* `\x` (making it also disappear from memory).

The initial comments use `arara` for speeding up compilation, not having to remember the command line for generating the nomenclature. They are of course optional.

[image]

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I've been trying to do, thanks!